# How to use variables with a period/dot stop in their name in SAS?

Tags: sas, statistics

I am confused about how to read variables names with a period/dot. the process stop on when it reads variable with dot/period;

my csv file looks like this:

[image]

here is my code:

[image]

what the log indicated:

[image]

Some of friends suggest me to change variables name, I did that several times, but the result makes me more frustrated:

[image]

Comment: SAS variable names cannot contain dots. They must only contain alpha-numeric plus underscores, not beginning with a number. Replace all the dots with underscores, and you'll be fine.

Comment: try using options validvarname =any;

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Actually the dataset is CSV file, if I change the " .  " to the " _ ", the whole data will change. This is another point that I cannot figure out

Comment: @Kiran, Thank you for your advise, what do you mean by   using options validvarname =any?  Is that validvarname indicate the variable name?

Comment: Changing the name you use for the variable will have no impact on the values it contains.

Comment: Changing a variable name should not change the input. You're likely doing something else wrong instead. Please post a reproducible example if this is occurring.

Comment: Show what the source file looks like. You posted a picture of a spreadsheet. A CSV is a text file.  Just post a few of the lines from the file.

Comment: Please post your text data (code, log, CSV) as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could try a simpler approach using proc import, it automatically converts dots(.) in a variable name into underscore

```
proc import datafile="X:\folder\sample.csv"
 out=out_ds
 dbms=csv
 replace;
 getnames=yes;
run;

data out_ds1;
 set out_ds;
 d_private=(private='Yes');
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this approach, and yes, it looks fine. However, since the dataset contain the variable that I want to construct it as the dummy variable. Would you like to tell me how to do that? for example, the variable Private, so appreciated! !

Comment: You may create dummy variable in next step, such as  -->
 data out_ds1; set out_ds;
 d_private=(private='Yes');
run;

Comment: That actually one of best way that address this problem! Thank you soooo much:)

Comment: Great, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Just fix your program to use valid names for your variables.

The names you use in your SAS code need to be valid SAS names.  But they do not have to exactly match the column headers in the text file you are trying to read.

Valid names are from 1 to 32 characters.  Start with either underscore or a letter and only include digits, letters or underscores.  For example you could use `Accept_pct` as the variable name for the variable that SAS is showing as being an error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  I have tried this way several times, however, it actually affect data...

Comment: actually I miss all of my dataset and every data become nothing

Comment: I don't see why this answer wouldn't solve your problem; you may not fully understand how to do it?

Comment: Show what you tried in your question. As text, not photographs.  Also so some example lines of the CSV file. Again as text only.

Comment: Finally I fixed it by transferring to .txt file... It might not be the best way, but at least works! Thank you for all of your response!

Comment: A CSV file IS a text file.  If the issue was just that it was not parsing the lines properly it probably was because your original INFILE statement did not include the DSD option.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the extended variable names option. Enclose the variables that have spaces or special characters in quotes with an n, like `'this'n`.

```
options validvarname=any;

data want;
    input var1 'var.2'n '3rd var'n;
    datalines;
1 2 3
;
run;
```

Comment: This is possible, and fixes the problem, but is not a good idea as it makes the program harder to maintain and manage.